# PHP file_exists will not work

Tags: php, file, exists, file-exists

I have been having problems with `file_exists` function in PHP that it always returns false, though the file is there as I can remove the if statement and it shows up fine.

```
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/profilepictures/1.png";
if (file_exists($filename) == true)
{
    $output .= '<img src="'.$filename.'" alt="profile picture" width="200"/>';
}
```

The `$filename` echos as:

```
/home/content/k/e/r/kernelkev/html/images/profilepictures/1.png
```

I have been googling this and most answers are to use the DOCUMENT_ROOT, but it still does not work for me.

Could anyone shed some light on this as it is really annoying me now.

---

This seemed to fix it...

```
$filename = "/images/profilepictures/1.png";
if (file_exists("..".$filename))
{
    $output .= '<img src="'.$filename.'" alt="profile picture" width="150"/>';
}
```

I have no idea why, but there we go.

Comment: Since `$filename` includes the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, I'd actually be fairly surprised if the code actually worked if you just took out the if statement.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should have mentioned I remove the document root from the start as i am aware php and html have different root paths

Comment: Try running the `$filename` through `realpath()` before checking whether the file exists. Other problem may be that there are some safe mode restrictions in place and they don't allow the function to look around an absolute file path.

Comment: An obvious thing to ask would be: Is the path you show as an example actually the correct one? If you haven't been including the leading slash in the `img src` attribute when it works correctly, it'd be easy to miss the effects of being one or more subdirectories off from where you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

If you use open_basedir in php.ini and use file_exists for file outside open_basedir path, you will not be warned at log and file_exists returns false even if file really exists.
file_exists will have trouble finding your file if the file permissions are not read enabled for 'other' when not owned by your php user. I thought I was having trouble with a directory name having a space in it (/users/andrew/Pictures/iPhoto Library/AlbumData.xml) but the reality was that there weren't read permissions on Pictures, iPhoto Library or AlbumData.xml. Once I fixed that, file_exists worked.
These will work fine for us with no problem as we confiugured server properly

Answer (score 0):

file_exists not working if the folder is forbidden. Try change your folder priviledge to 777 or 755 ?

```
sudo chmod 777 -R images/
```